# 7 boys and 5 girls sitting in a row, if no 2 girls are sitting together, find the permutations.

Tags: combinatorics

it's the question of math&stat, the way I think is 12! (no restrictions) - the permutations that 2 girls sitting together. But there are repeated cases, and i've puzzled and I realized that there're many experts here, so I hope my problem can be solved, thanks.

the answer is 3XXXXXXX

Comment: Could you say a little about the context of this question? How do you know the first digit?

Comment: it's the hint..

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Thank you. :)  i understood.

Answer (score 0):

Two girls that are siting together we can see as one girl they can sit in two ways.Two girls out of 5 we can choose in $\binom{5}{2}$ and all diferent positions are
$$2\cdot\binom{5}{2}\frac{(7+4)!}{7!4!}=6600$$

Comment: thx. but could u help me for the next steps? :) I've no idea.